# Архитектура приложения(игры) на Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Начал заниматься разработкой игр на Unity. При создании стали возникать проблемы с "чистотой" и "грамотностью" скриптов. Не могу найти или же придумать максимально грамотную схему построения архитектуры.

Подскажите где почитать максимально полезные советы об этой теме. Или же распишите свои мысли и советы по этому поводу.

P.s. подозреваю, что для разных игр - разные архитектуры, но мне кажется, что схожести в них все равно будут. Для удобства понимания моей проблемы, возьмем в пример такой жанр как  изометрический шутер: персонаж, зомби, дома, оружие и остальные прелести.

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-c)

Comment: И вот ещё неплохая статья была: https://habr.com/en/post/322258/

Comment: Информация из статьи безусловно полезная, но мне больше нужна информация о структуре всего приложения, а именно игры на UNITY. То есть как должны быть устроены классы, как грамотнее всего настроить их взаимодействие друг с другом, как лучше разделять логику и тд и тп.

Comment: Похвально. Тогда читайте фундаментальные книжки. Могу посоветовать обратить особое внимание на Боба Мартина "Чистый код". Это совсем не про юнити, но на данном этапе вашего понимания архитектур будет очень полезно.

Comment: Ага, тут Unity в архитектуре особой роли не играет. Используя паттер MVP, бизнес логика не связана с призентром, который тесно работает с объектами Unity, разве что использует базовые структуры типа `Vector3`, `Rect` и некоторые классы.

Comment: Ну я могу понять разделение логики на бизнес и на отображение, но... а как быть в unity. Если там все заключается в прописывании скриптов

Comment: @Relax, кто тебе сказал такую чушь? `C#` полноценный ооп язык, как и другие.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почитав коменты.... вообще я не согласен с мнением что в случае с юнити поможет "чистый код". У юнити есть свои особенности и они буквально заставляют программиста писать неправильно или строить проект неправильно.  Читал я чистый код и юнити меня все равно заставлял во многих местах писать неправильно и учится на собственных ошибках.

Уверен, что лучше читать конкретную литературу которая будет рассказывать конкретно про юнити. Тем более, что НЕВОЗМОЖНО написать код который бы не противоречил каким-то паттернам. Даже читая "чистый код" можно увидеть множество правил которые противоречат одно второму в рамках одной книги (что, к слову, автор так же выделял!). Нету универсального правильного подхода - всегда будут компромисы при написании кода.

Из того что сходу вспомню по вопросу(не совсем про архитектуру, скорее в целом советы), так это:

- Не использовать старый GUI, а лишь новый юай на канвасе
- Не использовать захардкодженные кнопки управления, для этого есть Input manager или как-то так
- По мере необходимости использовать DontDestroyOnLoad - например когда нужно всегда держать в памяти теперешние настройки при переходе между уровнями. Все что нужно тебе на разных сценах не должно выгружаться из памяти что бы потом заново загружаться.
- используй асинхронную загрузку сцен
- минимально использовать поля инспектора в которые ты привязываешь обьект на сцене или префаб. Лучше если ты их будешь искать в скрипте в Start/Awake на сцене или же в самом проэкте искать префаб кодом. Будут постоянно отвалитваться если проэкт чуть больше однодневки и будешь тратить много времени впустую.
- Использовать движения на основе физики - обойдешь много багов. Переходи на нефизическое движение исключительно в крайних случаях.
- Ищи скрипты-компоненты всегда в Start/Awake. Если ты делаешь GetComponent<> в другом месте - практически наверняка ты делаешь что-то не так и это приведет к тормозам
- Если тебе нужно менеджить обьекты - лучше сохраняй ссылку на них в каком-то скрипте менеджере. Достать обьект из этого менеджера быстрее чем заново искать этот же обьект по сцене в большинстве случаев.
- никогда не применяй Try Catch - тормоза на пустом месте. Заменяй на if else
- Используй атрибуты к параметрам (вроде `[Range(1, 6)]` ) - они облегчают жизнь. Но помни об особенности юнити - применяя атрибут ты можешь словить неожиданное поведение. Например изменив дефолтное значение в коде, оно не поменяется в инспекторе.
- Если один компонет требует наличие другого - обязательно используй атрибут `required component`
- Чем меньше связность между обьектами - тем лучше.

Comment: `минимально использовать поля инспектора в которые ты привязываешь обьект на сцене или префаб`... Прощай нормальная каталоголизаия сущностей и привет папочка `Resourses` на пару с `GameObject.Find`... дорогие связи на соплях... мда. На тему последнего пункта, хоть поясни, что ты про интерфейсы.

Comment: Честно говоря я не нашел, что искал, но спасибо за советы. Хотя я не совсем понимаю, чем хуже сделать одно поле в инспекторе, чем 3-5 строк для поиска обьекта на сцене. А если мне нужен какой-то определенный обьект, скажем кнопка. А у меня их на сцене 10. То как я через FindObjectOfType<> найду нужную?!

Comment: @Relax потому что обьект который прикреплен в поле время от времени по тех или иных причинах отваливается. А теперь представь что у тебя таких полей может быть 100,200,300 на разных обьектах. И написание 3-5 строк может тебе по времени быть значительно дешевле чем поддерживать те связи вручную. Впрочем, можешь считать что это чисто мой опыт, вполне вероятно что твой опыт будет иным :)

Comment: @Andrew это не твой опыт, а твой косяк. Само без причин ничего не отваливается.  Нарерняка у тебя это было связано с кастомным редаетором, потому, что ты не делал `EditorUtility.SetDirty(target)` и после закрытия проекта значения не сеаризовались и пропадали. У меня тоже было, но мне не показалось, что это дифект `Unity`.

Comment: У меня не было кастомного редактора там. И не было проблем с НЕ СОХРАНЕНИЕМ. У меня были проблемы с периодическим(а не постоянным) слетанием присвоенных значений. А причин разных было штук пять. Но уже не помню каких, если чесно :) Вроде проблем при переносе обьектов с одной сцены в другую, обновления префабов или еще в каких-то ситуациях. Вобщем, я поделился своим личным опытом. Впрочем, кроме меня здесь никто опытом не поделился - а хоть что-то лучше чем ничего. Если у тебя есть свои подходы и заметки - мне самому было бы интересно их почитать :)